# finished / unfinished progressive actions

Tags: grammar

I am new here, so forgive me if I do something improper. I've been wondering what makes it clear if the action was ongoing and completed or ongoing and uncompleted. 
Short dialogue:

X: Oh, you look wet.

Y: I've been washing my car.

Is the **action of washing the car** finished and progressive for some time in the past ( the person was cleaning the car for some time and finished it) or progressive but unfinished ( the person was cleaning the car for some time, but for some reason didn't complete the job )?

Or maybe we can't clearly spot the difference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to ELU! You might find some answers for this kind of thing among the existing questions  on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com). It’s a valid question, though. In the dialogue example, I would say the washing is finished: "I have been..." vs "I am...". However, you **"have been wondering"**, but I dare say you are still wondering, so the wondering is not yet finished!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Let's put aside the fact that the action could be still going on. Let's place the progressive "washing the car" action in the past, which is mentioned to explain the current "wet" state of the person. How to figure out whether the action was completed or just left uncompleted?

Answer (score 1):

"I have been washing my car"
This sentence uses the tense known as [present perfect progressive](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/present_perfect_progressive.htm). It is used for actions that started in the past and may or may not be finished. Some other context is needed (or assumed) to ascertain whether the action has finished or not.

In the case of "I have been washing my car", I would assume the car washing is complete. If it was ongoing, [present progressive](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/present_progressive.htm) "I am washing my car" would be used (and there would be evidence of car washing).

In the case of "I have been wondering...", I would assume that the wondering continues. If it was complete, the [simple past](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/simple_past.htm) tense "I wondered" would be used. Wondering is internal, there might be no outward evidence, so best to assume a steady state.

Both these examples are personal interpretation, though. It’s easier and clearer to use other tenses instead: "I just washed the car" (simple past); "I was washing the car" (past progressive); "I am washing the car" (present progressive).

Comment: Taking into consideration another situation: 

[* X: I should mend a dripping tap in the kitchen, but I don't know how.

Y: I can try to do it. I've been reading a book about hydraulics. *]

Does "I've been reading a book" imply that the speaker was riffling through the pages and gathered the useful information, but didn't read the entire book. 

If "I've read a book" were used instead, would it change the meaning into " the speaker read the entire book (from the beginning to the end), so he/she knows what to do with the dripping tap"?

Is my thinking correct? Thanks once again!